# Number of ways to partition $2 \times N.$ Tile into $m$ parts

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, tiling

Given a $2 \times N$  Tile , how to find the number of ways to partition it into $M$ parts ?

Meaning of a part : Cells having same number which are adjacent to each other form a part .

Lets take $N = 5$ ,  so an example tile looks like  :

1 1 1 2 2

3 3 2 2 1

This tile has 4-parts to it :

Part-1 : (1 1 1)

Part-2 :

```
     (X 2 2)

     (2 2 X)
```

Part-3 : (3 3)

Part-4 : (1)

Each cell can be assigned any number between $1$ and $K$ , how many ways exist to partition the tile into "M" parts ?

Number of different tile-configurations possible are : $k^x$ , where $x = 2n$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can build a recursion out of it. Notice that either the last column has the same piece or two of them. Call $A_n\in \mathbb{Z}[q]$ the polynomial such that $$A_n(q)=\sum _{i=1}^{2n}A_{n,i}q^i,$$ where $A_{n,i}$ is the number of such tilings with $i$ parts such that the last column has just one part and $B_n$ is such that
$$B_n(q)=\sum _{i=1}^{2n}B_{n,i}q^i,$$
where $B_{n,i}$ are the tilings with $i$ parts and ends with a column having two parts. You are interested in $[q^m](A_n(q)+B_n(q)).$
One can build a recurrence by understanding how to connect the last column to the right so $$A_n(q) = A_{n-1}(q)+q(k-1)A_{n-1}(q)+(k-2)qB_{n-1}(q)+2B_{n-1}(q)$$
because you can either place a column of the same color as before, or change the color(so create a new part, that is why we multiply by $q$) or you can put a new part to a column of disconnected pieces. So you get
$$A_{n}(q)=(1+q(k-1))A_{n-1}(q)+((k-2)q+2)B_{n-1}(q),$$
Analogously do it for $B_n$ getting
$$B_{n}(q)=(q^2(k-1)(k-2)+2q(k-1))A_{n-1}(q)+(1+2q(k-2)+q^2((k-1)(k-2)+1))B_{n-1}(q),$$
where $A_1(q)=kq$ and $B_1(q)=k(k-1)q^2.$

You can try generating functions or any method you know for solving these systems of recurrences.

Comment: +1 I essentially get the same recurrence relation but the corresponding OCF in $q$ looks like a nightmare...

Comment: @achillehui Thanks! Yes, I did not want to cry doing it. Also perhaps is easier to consider the matrix. Perhaps diagonalize??. At least one can obtain the result for $n$ in $O(n\log(n)).$

Comment: I am worried, that "m" is never used anywhere in the equations...why ?

Comment: If I want to calculate what the question asked for , what will be A1(q) and B1(q) ? As q is not mentioned in the question , I don't know what value to put for it so I calculate in O(N)

Comment: Can I solve it for m=1,2,3,........2*n in O(nlogn) time ?

Comment: I am more interested in calculating A(n,i) and B(n,i) for all "i" from 1 to 2n. Please help!!

Comment: @RelaxRelaxation Yes, it is. $q$ is a variable that serves as condensing the numbers in a polynomial. To recover the numbers, you expand the polynomial(for example, using derivatives). To avoid horrible sums. You can get a $O(n\cdot log(n))$ by considering binary exponentiation. Notice that this is a system of linear recurrences. I suggest you do examples. Als